# Alignment in iText library for java

Tags: java, pdf, alignment, itext

I just got a question about alignment in the library iText. Say if i was to do a quote program.

For example
On the Left side of the page I would want to put Quote # 01 and on the same line on the other side of the page I want to put the date.

Is this possible using the Paragraph class? If not can any body help me out with any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't do this within a single paragraph. You'll have to get the current position (`cb.getYLine()`) and place a separate chunk with the date. See [itext positioning text absolutely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625455/itext-positioning-text-absolutely) if you need pointers on placing the chunk.