# How to add text to an existing pdf at a fixed position?

Tags: pdf, itext

I must insert a number at a fix position in an existing A4 pdf.
I've tried the following as a first test, but that doesn't work(not text is added).
What goes wrong?
Here's my code:

```
byte[] omrMarks = omrFrame.getOmrImage();
Jpeg img = new Jpeg(omrMarks);
PdfImportedPage page = stamper.getImportedPage(source, pageNum);
PdfContentByte pageContent = stamper.getOverContent(pageNum);

pageContent.addImage(
  img, img.getWidth(), 0, 0, img.getHeight(), 15f, (page.getHeight() - 312));
pageContent.moveTo(10, 200);
pageContent.beginText();
pageContent.setLiteral("Test");
pageContent.endText();
```

Comment: what version of itext are you using?

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625455/itext-positioning-text-absolutely

Comment: did you look at the other question's answer?

Comment: i followed the link you supplied and now it works well!!
Many Thanks!

Comment: feel free to upvote one of my many answers :)

Comment: @SiegfriedStorr You added "solved" to your title. The style here is to accept an answer. This explicitly tells other people exactly what helped you. http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 3):

There are many issues with this question.

This is certainly wrong:

```
pageContent.moveTo(10, 200);
pageContent.beginText();
pageContent.setLiteral("Test");
pageContent.endText();
```

- The `moveTo()` method doesn't make sense; it has no effect on the text state object.
- The text state object is illegal because there's no `setFontAndSize()` (it's very odd that this doesn't throw a `RuntimeException`, are you using an obsolete version of iText?)
- The `setLiteral()` method should only be used to add some literal PDF syntax to a content stream.

For instance, something like:

```
pageContent.setLiteral("\n100 100 m\n100 200 l\nS\n");
```

should only be used if you understand that the following PDF syntax draws a line:

```
100 100 m
100 200 l
S
```

It's clear from your question that you don't understand PDF syntax, so you shouldn't use these methods. Instead you should use convenience methods such as the `showTextAligned()` method, which hide the complexity of PDF and save you a couple of lines.

Maybe you have a good reason to opt for the "hard way", but in that case, you should read the documentation, otherwise you'll continue using methods such as `setLiteral()` instead of `showText()`, `moveTo()` instead of `moveText()`, and so on, resulting in code you don't want your employer to see.

Furthermore, you're making the assumption that the lower left corner of the page has the coordinates `(0,0)`. That's probably true for the majority of PDF documents found in the wild, but that's not true for all PDF documents. The `MediaBox` doesn't have to be `[0 0 595 842]`, it could as well be `[595 842 1190 1684]`. Moreover: what if there's a `CropBox`? Maybe you're adding content that isn't visible because it's cropped away...