# How to underline text with a dotted line?

Tags: java, itext, paragraphs

I need to merge 2 paragraphs, the first is a sequence of dots, and the second is the text that I want write on dots:

```
        Paragraph pdots1 = new Paragraph("......................................................................................................................",font10);
        Paragraph  pnote= new Paragraph("Some text on the dots", font10);
```

I tried to play with:
            pnote.setExtraParagraphSpace(-15);
But this mess up the next paragraphs. I tried too with this: [itext positioning text absolutely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625455/itext-positioning-text-absolutely)
and works fine but only if my pdf size is fixed. So don't solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a good idea to use a String with dots when you need a dotted line. It's better to use a dotted line created using the `DottedLineSeparator` class. See for instance the [`UnderlineWithDottedLine`](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/UnderlineWithDottedLine) example.

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This line will be underlined with a dotted line.");
DottedLineSeparator dottedline = new DottedLineSeparator();
dottedline.setOffset(-2);
dottedline.setGap(2f);
p.add(dottedline);
document.add(p);
```

In this example (see [underline_dotted.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/underline_dotted.pdf) for the result), I add the line 2 points under the baseline of the paragraph (using the `setOffset()` method) and I define a gap of 2 points between the dots (using the `setGap()` method).

Comment: Thanks lot, very helpful tip, used to add use a String with dots coz i ddnt know `DottedLineSeparator` class, now thanks!