# How to set text @ absolute position in the PDF Document using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to use [@aaronbartell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625455/itext-positioning-text-absolutely) example, to place the text at required (absolute) position in the PDF document. please give me some direction, thanks.

Example:

```
private static void absText(String text, int x, int y) {
  try {
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    cb.saveState();
    cb.beginText();
    cb.moveText(x, y);
    cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 12);
    cb.showText(text);
    cb.endText();
    cb.restoreState();
  } catch (DocumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: Well yes - where are you *expecting* the `writer` variable to come from? I think that answer is expecting there to already be an appropriate writer available...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use iText, you create a PDF document in 5 steps"

1. Create a `Document` instance
2. Create a `PdfWriter` instance
3. Open the document
4. Add content
5. Close the document

In your question, you do not create the `PdfWriter` instance (unless it's a global variable). In your comment, you do not open the document (you've skipped step 3 and this step is essential in the document creation process).

Take the code from your comment, and add the following line at the appropriate place:

```
document.open();
```

The appropriate place is *after* the line where you create the `PdfWriter` instance and *before* you start using the `writer` instance.

**Update**

In your comment, you are now sharing some code that contains a logical error.

Your main method `pdfGeneration()` (probably) contains the five steps in the creating process:

1. You create a `Document` instance
2. You create a `PdfWriter` instance that writes bytes to a file **My First PDF Doc.pdf**
3. You open the document
4. You call a method `setPara()` that is supposed to add content
5. You close the document (not visible in your code)

The logical error can be found in the `setPara()` method. In this method, you repeat the five steps. You create a **new** `Document` instance (there's no need to do this) and you create a **new** `PdfWriter` instance that creates a **new** file **My First PDF Doc.pdf**. This throws an exception, because that file is already in use!

You should change `setPara()` like this:

```
public void setPara(PdfContentByte canvas, Phrase p, float x, float y) {
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, phrase, x, y, 0);
}
```

You should call this method from your main method like this:

```
setPara(writer.getDirectContent(), new Phrase(text), x, y);
```

Of course: as the `setPara()` method is little more than a reduced version of the `showTextAligned()` method that already exists in iText, you may want to use that method directly. For instance: use this in your main method, instead of introducing a `setPara()` method:

```
Phrase phrase = new Phrase("Some text", new Font());
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, phrase, 20, 20, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks @Bruno Lowagie again, when I followed your steps, this time no error but the file is [corrupt](http://i.imgur.com/0lzmWaM.png).

Comment: Can you share the PDF instead of the screen shot? The error message you show is very typical if you forget to close the document. Did you close the document?

Comment: Thanks @Bruno Lowagie, PDF [screen shot](http://i.imgur.com/uOpxRch.png), the actual code where I am calling the [function](http://i.imgur.com/2H4AqNr.png)

Comment: There is a serious logical error in your code: you are damaging the file you are creating! I'll update my answer.

Comment: You don't need to write your own method to do this, the `showTextAligned()` method in the `ColumnText` class takes care of your requirement (as shown in my updated answer).

Comment: Thanks @Bruno Lowagie, I am very sorry to waste you time, I made it more complicated. Now it works [beautifully](http://i.imgur.com/VetqIfK.png), Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes indeed, you (@Bruno Lowagie) solved it very very quickly! I think! need to point this answer to the other [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625455/itext-positioning-text-absolutely) as well.