# Where is the Origin (x,y) of a PDF page?

Tags: java, pdf, text, itext

I am using `iText` to create my **PDF** files.

I want to position text at some specific place in the document using the method I found here: [itext positioning text absolutely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625455/itext-positioning-text-absolutely#).

However, I cannot figure out where to find the origin of the coordinate system of the page.

`bottom left corner`? `top right corner`? `bottom right corner`? `top left corner`?

***Where is this origin?***

Comment: It depends: are you talking about documents created from scratch, or about existing documents?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie documents created from scratch

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The dimensions of a page (aka the page boundaries) are defined in a page dictionary:

- `/MediaBox`: the boundaries of the physical medium (the page). This value is mandatory, so you'll find it in every PDF.
- `/CropBox`: the region that is visible when displayed or printed. The `/CropBox` is equal to or smaller than the `/MediaBox`. This value is optional; if it's missing, the `/CropBox` is equal to the `/MediaBox`.
- Other possible values are the `/BleedBox`, `/TrimBox` and `/ArtBox`. These have been defined for specific purposes, but they aren't used that often anymore. If they are missing, they default to the `/CropBox`. None of these values can outsize the `/CropBox`.

When you create a document with iText, you define the `/MediaBox` either explicitly or implicitly.

Explicitly:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(20, 20, 300, 600);
Document document = new Document(rect);
```

Implicitly:

```
Document document = new Document();
```

This single line is equivalent to:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 595, 842);
Document document = new Document(rect);
```

The four parameters passed to the `Rectangle` constructor (`llx`, `lly`, `urx`, `ury`) define a rectangle using the x and y coordinates of the lower-left and the upper-right corner.

In case of `new Rectangle(0, 0, 595, 842)`, the lower-left corner of the page coincides with the origin of the coordinate system `(0, 0)`. The upper-right corner of the page coincides with the coordinate `(595, 842)`.

All measurements are defined in user units, and by default, the user units *roughly* corresponds with the typographic point: 1 user unit = 1 point.

Note the word *roughly*: we use points to do calculations, but in the ISO standard, we are very cautious not to use point as a synonym for user unit. For instance: an A4 page measures 595 by 842 user units, but if you'd calculate the exact value in points, there would be a slight difference (some numbers after the point).

The lower-left corner of the page isn't always the origin of the coordinate system. If we define a page using `Rectangle(20, 20, 300, 600)`, the origin is 20 user units below and 20 user units to the left of the lower-left corner. It's also possible to use negative values to define a page size.

For instance: suppose that you want to create an A2 document consisting of 4 A4 pages, than you could define the page sizes like this:

```
Rectangle(-595, 0, 0, 842)   Rectangle(0, 0, 595, 842)
Rectangle(-595, -842, 0, 0)  Rectangle(0, -842, 595, 0);
```

By defining the media box like this, you also pass information with respect to the relative position of the different pages. If you look at the 4 A4 pages as a unit, the origin of the coordinate system is the exact center of the A2 page.

**Important:**

All of the above assumes that you didn't introduce any coordinate transformations, e.g. using the `concatCTM()` or `transform()` method. These methods allow you to change the coordinate system, for instance change the angle between the x and y axis from 90 degrees (the default) to another angle. You can also scale an axis to get a different aspect ratio. While it's certainly fun to do this, it requires quite some Math.

Comment: Straight to the point answer, thanks!!! Good explanation. Let me work with it to see what comes out.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that in most PDF generators, PDF page origin is from the left bottom (0,0).

```
1 inch = 72 points and 1 cm = 1/2.54 inch = 0.3937 inch = 28.3 points.
where,
(lower left x coordinate)l l x=margin from left.
(lower left y coordinate)l l y=margin from bottom(bottom of rectangle)
(upper right x coordinate)u r x=width of article
(upper right y coordinate)u r y=margin from bottom of upper boundary of article.
```

To draw a Rectangle in PDF, using such generators, which contain A-4 size pages then, you need to define Rectangle as:

```
rectangle = new Rectangle(25, 25, 575, 820);
rectangle. set Border(Rectangle.BOX);
rectangle. set Border Width(1);
document.add(rectangle);
```

Comment: *"Please note that PDF page origin is from the left bottom(0,0)."* - that merely *often* is the case because most PDF generator create PDFs that way. It is not enforced by the PDF standard, the origin actually can be anywhere inside or outside the bounds of the page.