# How to center align a long text in itextsharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I'm developing a label automating system using itextsharp with C#. I needed to center a selected and it should be goes to a new line if the page width exceeded. Text should be in a given position too. Please help!!!

I tries using paragraphs, chunks and even showtextaligned method. But non of them work.

```
cb.SetFontAndSize(bfTimes, 5);
cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
cb.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER,"this is a sample text",50,50,0);
```

When using paragraphs, text was center aligned but cannot place it in a required position. when using a ShowTextAligned method, text didn't align or move to a new line.

Comment: The anchor point is important to place position. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280015/itextsharp-showtextaligned-anchor-point you should check your anchor position then set x y coordinate

Comment: Yeah! I got it. Thanks.

Comment: Good.!! it is better if you put your solution here so it helpful for others.